# On click function JS make dynamic

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, onclick

I have a menu with 7 tabs and 7 functions to trigger onClick event, but right now my function is static.
how to make the code more shorter and dynamic ?

Source for code (example for one TAB)
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_dropdown.asp

functions from 1 to 7

```
  function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

//for etc... up to 7

function myFunction7() {
    document.getElementById("myDropdown2").classList.toggle("show2");
}
```

onClick Event from 1 to 7

```
window.onclick = function(event) {


  matches = event.target.matches ? event.target.matches('.dropbtn, .fa-briefcase') : event.target.msMatchesSelector('.dropbtn, .fa-briefcase');
    if (!matches) {
        var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
            var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
            if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
                openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
            }
        }
    }


// etc up to 7

matches = event.target.matches ? event.target.matches('.dropbtn7, .fa-motorcycle') : event.target.msMatchesSelector('.dropbtn7, .fa-motorcycle');
    if (!matches) {
        var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content7");
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
            var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
            if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show7')) {
                openDropdown.classList.remove('show7');
            }
        }
    }



// end of click event

}
```

Comment: Where are you using `myFunction`s?

Comment: <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn" > .... </buton>

Comment: @ivanko I take it you're new to JS? Also I suggest you use `className` over `classList`, just for better support across browsers. IE9 doesn't support classList, as an example.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

### Review

Firstly, I'm assuming you're new to JavaScript, if you're not, then I don't know what to say, but let's just say you are. Firstly, that's a horrible way to do things. Not only could other scripts assign events to the window click event, which may cause serious bugs with your code, but exposing things to the global scope is quite bad.

I suggest you look at encapsulating things into objects, like I've done in my example below, and you then look at the JavaScript module design pattern, trust me, it'll pay off.

---

### My Solution

As you can see in the code below, I've assigned events to individual dom elements, this makes event handlers much easier to maintain firstly, I also find that it makes the code a lot neater.

Sure, the initial code for the object I've defined `EventHandlerObject`, it looks bulky at a glance, but thanks to using the key word `prototype`, you can add to and extend the object as much as you like, you can even make an object so that it can add certain functions/features dynamically.

```js
function EventHandlerObject() {
  // basic singleton implementation 
  if (EventHandlerObject.instance !== null 
   && typeof EventHandlerObject.instance !== "undefined") {
   return this.instance;
  } else { EventHandlerObject.instance = this; }
}


EventHandlerObject.prototype.action = function (obj, eventType, callback) {
  if (typeof obj === "undefined" || obj === null) { return; }
  if (obj.length || obj instanceof Array) {
    for (var i = 0, s = obj.length; i < s; i++) {
      var elm = obj[i];
      try { // try to remove the event
        if (elm.removeEventListener) { elm.removeEventListener(eventType, callback, false); }
        else { elm[eventType + callback] = null; }
      } catch (e) { console.log(e); }

      try { // try to add the event and callback
        if (elm.addEventListener) { elm.addEventListener(eventType, callback, false); }
        else if (elm.attachEvent) { elm.attachEvent('on' + eventType, callback); }
        else { elm["on"+eventType] = callback; }
      } catch (e) { console.log(e); }
    }
  } else {
    try { // try to remove the event
      if (obj.removeEventListener) { obj.removeEventListener(eventType, callback, false); }
      else { obj[eventType + callback] = null; }
    } catch (e) { console.log(e); }

    try { // try to add the event and callback
      if (obj.addEventListener) { obj.addEventListener(eventType, callback, false); }
      else if (obj.attachEvent) { obj.attachEvent('on' + eventType, callback); }
      else { obj["on"+eventType] = callback; }
    } catch (e) { console.log(e); }
  }
};


var elms = document.querySelectorAll(".dropbtn, .fa-briefcase");
var events = new EventHandlerObject();
events.action(elms, "click", function(){
  var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
    var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
    if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
      openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
    }
  }
});


var otherElms = document.querySelectorAll(".dropbtn7, .fa-motorcycle");
events.action(otherElms, "click", function(){
  var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content7");
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
    var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
    if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show7')) {
      openDropdown.classList.remove('show7');
    }
  }
});
```

---

### Additionals

I suggest you do a lot of learning, a good place I find to learn JavaScript from scratch would be [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/). When I was trying to learn **everything** from scratch from design patterns to using API's, etc, I personally think it's an exceptional source for learning, not only does it teach you how to do certain things, but it also tells you what browser supports what functionality which is a **beautiful** feature, especially when you want to find out asap rather than testing/doing additional research.

Comment: thanks Ill try out.
I was following this Example

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_dropdown.asp

Comment: @ivanko while W3Schools is *okay* for learning the basics, it's **awful** when you want to learn more in depth topics, such as design patterns. Their examples are **just** examples to be fair, they're not meant to be taken and implemented in reality, like that example you've shared, I hope they've got it there as one way to do it. In the real world, when you're working with 1000's of lines of JS all the time, you need to encapsulate things, and you **NEED** to learn and understand design patters, such as the singleton design pattern that I implemented above (although not in the best way).